How do you get a list of day and month names in the Python standard library?
I have some custom date code that needs the names of the days and months as lists.
I would expect to find them in the standard library somewhere, but time and datetime don't seem to have them. I could define my own lists, or use time.strftime() to get each name, but that seems clunky. How/where can I get lists of day names and month names?

You were looking in the wrong base libraries to get those lists, what you needed was -
import calendar
print(list(calendar.month_name))
print(list(calendar.day_name))

gets you a list of months and days of the week

Perfect! For all my searching I never found that other question :-(

Note that the month list starts with an empty string; January is at index 1.
